# Get pid of posted image by using graph api

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

By using Facebook graph API, how can I get the pid of a posted image?

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos/"
                             parameters:params
                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
 {
         NSString *ID = [result objectForKey:@"post_id"];
         NSLog(@"pid  =  %@",ID);
     NSLog(@"Details = %@", [result description]);
                      }];
```

actually it's retaining some different id and i will post id also by use of this how can i get pid of the posted image?